Please help on First Post Reviews
Good news! We have lots of new users asking questions on Bitcoin.Stackexchange.com. 
However, that means that we currently get about 20-30 new reviews every day. Especially, Badr Bellaj, Jestin, and Andrew Chow have been a great help this past month. I'm also trying to do at least ten reviews per day, yet our queues still grow faster than we work through them. 
My goal is to help Bitcoin.SE to graduate from the Beta. To that end, I'm striving to attract a few more regular users which seems more likely to happen if we provide a good first impression by quickly addressing their posts. We could use your help! Even one review per day would be splendid!
Especially on the First Post queue please check:

if the title describes the topic
the tags fit the question
for duplicates

Please also feel free to vote early and often, including downvoting bad questions. Upvoting and downvoting increases/decreases visibility of content on our landing page. Bad questions are cleaned automatically after a while.
Thank you for your help!
